# Converting object to float in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following this tutorial : 
https://sites.psu.edu/bdssblog/2017/04/06/basic-data-visualization-in-unity-scatterplot-creation/

It is suppose to create plot from data. Simply reading x,y,z positions from csv file and display in 3d scene as point. 
And I faced obstacle. This function is used to convert from object to float :

**float y = System.Convert.ToSingle( object );**

And it doesnt work for all data. It seems to stop the code. I tried also converting first ToString(), **float.Parse** and **TryParse**. And it is all the same. 
I tried with some other csv file and it also wont work.

But when i simply take x,y,z as object and display it by Debug.Log, it displays every value fine. 
So it is not about the data but about converting it to float.

I stuck. Any ideas ? It really doesnt make sense:(

PS. I am using Unity 2019.3.9

Comment: Im not going to read the tutorial,, so, can you show what text you read in, what you converted it to and why you arent just converting the text to float?

Answer (score 0):

Like the tutorial says...

> I want to point out that System.Convert.ToSingle simply ensures the value given by pointList is a float

And it uses it like this:

`System.Convert.ToSingle(csvFile[row][columnName]);`

while you use it like this:

`float y = System.Convert.ToSingle( object );`

which will not work, since you cannot expect it to convert an complex object to a floating number. You need to send the single csvFile string value, and parse a float from it, like the tutorial suggests.

Comment: Yes, I am doing exacly how tutorial says. And now it works for x values (I assing x by System.Convert.ToSingle(pointlist[i][column]) and y and z assigned to random value to check it) , but while reading y and z it just stoppes. And i dont know why.

Comment: then you haven't showed us your real code, since you wrote `float y = System.Convert.ToSingle( object );`. How can we help if you don't show what you've done, but instead explain the correct way of doing it, and just "saying" that you're doing it correctly. I can only respond with "ok, good - you're doing it correctly so there is a magical error"

Comment: Yeah, sorry you right. I wrote object, because unity told me that type which csvfile[row][column] returns is object type. This is CSV reader which returns list with string and object : https://github.com/tikonen/blog/blob/master/csvreader/CSVReader.cs

Comment: And because it was object type i thought that the problem is about converting it to float